# pass an array from jQuery to PHP (and actually go to the page after submit)

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

This seems like it would have been simple, but what i was doing was creating an array in jQuery and sending it to a php via ajax and inserting the records into a db. But what i want to do now is create the array exactly the same but instead of ajax, i'd like to go to the php page and view what it has received.

How would i go about doing this?

I'm using this jQuery:

```
$('#preview').live('click',function(){ 

                    var postData = {};
                    $('#items tr').not(':first').each(function(index, value) {
                        var keyPrefix = 'data[' + index + ']';
                        postData[keyPrefix + '[index]'] = index;
                        postData[keyPrefix + '[supp_short_code]'] = $(this).closest('tr').find('.supp_short_code').text();
                        postData[keyPrefix + '[project_ref]'] = $(this).closest('tr').find('.project_ref').text();
                        postData[keyPrefix + '[om_part_no]'] = $(this).closest('tr').find('.om_part_no').text();
                        postData[keyPrefix + '[description]'] = $(this).closest('tr').find('.description').text();
                        postData[keyPrefix + '[quantity_input]'] = $(this).closest('tr').find('.quantity_input').val();
                        postData[keyPrefix + '[cost_of_items]'] = $(this).closest('tr').find('.cost_of_items').text();
                        postData[keyPrefix + '[cost_total_td]'] = $(this).closest('tr').find('.cost_total_td').text();
                    });

                $.ajax
                    ({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "preview.php",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: postData,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function()
                        {
                        }
                    });

            });
```

And this PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['data']) && is_array($_POST['data'])) {
                foreach ($_POST['data'] as $row => $data) {
                    echo $data['index'];
                    echo $data['project_ref'];
                    echo $data['supp_short_code'];
                    echo $data['om_part_no'];
                    echo $data['description']; 
                    echo $data['quantity_input']; 
                    echo $data['cost_of_items']; 
                    echo $data['cost_total_td'];
                }
            }
```

Comment: What is it that you get? Any error message? What is your problem?

Comment: Sorry, theres no error, but what i'm saying is that this is using ajax, what i want to do is like a hyperlink and actually go to the php page. Not just get an ajax response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do, following on from what ***dnagirl*** said, is to generate the POST form using jQuery and submit it.

```
$('#preview').live('click',function(){ 
    var cForm = $('<form method="post">').attr('action', "preview.php");
    $('#items tr').not(':first').each(function(index, value) {
        var keyPrefix = 'data[' + index + ']';

        cForm.append($('<input type="hidden">').attr('name', keyPrefix + '[index]').val(index));
        cForm.append($('<input type="hidden">').attr('name', keyPrefix + '[supp_short_code]').val($(this).closest('tr').find('.supp_short_code').text());
        // etc
    });

    cForm.hide().append('body').submit();
    return false;
});
```

The reason for using attr() in places rather than inline within the creation string is to avoid issues with escaping, and it looks cleaner in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

You can store the received data in a session:

```
if (isset($_POST['data']) && is_array($_POST['data'])) {
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['data'] = $_POST['data'];
}
```

And then link to another PHP page that retrieves the data from the session and displays it:

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['data']) && is_array($_SESSION['data'])) {
                foreach ($_SESSION['data'] as $row => $data) {
                    echo $data['index'];
                    echo $data['project_ref'];
                    echo $data['supp_short_code'];
                    echo $data['om_part_no'];
                    echo $data['description']; 
                    echo $data['quantity_input']; 
                    echo $data['cost_of_items']; 
                    echo $data['cost_total_td'];
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use JSON

[PHP JSON](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php)

Answer (score 0):

So you are current creating a POST string using jQuery and then sending it using ajax to a php script.  Now you actually want to POST directly to PHP.  Is that correct?

If I've got that right, there are 2 options:

1. actually POST from a form that
   the user fills out
2. have a skeleton form consisting of
   the `<form>` tags and a submit
   button.  Use jQuery to create and
   populate hidden form fields when the
   user hits the submit button and
   before the submit action is
   completed.

Comment: Thats correct, maybe i'm being naive but can i not just stick postData in a hyperlink or something? Is that possible?

Comment: @benhowdle89: you can put GET data in a hyperlink, not POST data.  If your fields are only for pulling data, then GET is a reasonable way to go.  But if you are changing things with the fields (e.g. updating a database), POST should be used.