# jquery add to array then submit and pass data not working

Tags: php, jquery, html, arrays

My problem is:
I'm trying to submit an array of hidden input types, which are stacked into an array using jquery onclick, to a PHP file. However, when I try to count or even echo the passed variable in the php file (saveTest.php), no data appears or the count variable is zero.
I've searched and I found this guy's question:
[pass an array from jQuery to PHP (and actually go to the page after submit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207222/pass-an-array-from-jquery-to-php-and-actually-go-to-the-page-after-submit)

I think I'm close to the above post but I'm still a newbie in jQuery so I don't understand much of the codes.
This is my jquery:

```
$(function(){
  $("td").click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("on"))
 {
    alert("Already marked absent");

 }
else
{

    $(this).addClass("on");
    var currentCellText = $(this).text();
    $("#collect").append("<input type='text' hidden = '" + currentCellText + "'/>" + currentCellText);
 }
});

$("#clicky").click(function(){
    $("td").removeClass("on");
    $("#collect").text('');
    $("#collect").append("Absentees: <br>")
});
});

<?php
session_start();
include 'connectdb.php';
$classID = $_SESSION['csID'];

$classQry = "SELECT e.csID, c.subjCode, c.section, b.subj_name, e.studentID, CONCAT(s.lname, ', ' , s.fname)name
FROM ENROLLMENT e, CLASS_SCHEDULE c, STUDENT s, SUBJECT b
WHERE e.csID = c.csID
AND c.csID = '" . $classID . "'
AND c.subjCode = b.subjCode
AND e.studentID = s.studentID
ORDER BY e.sort;";

$doClassQry = mysql_query($classQry);

echo "<table id='tableone'>";
    while($x = mysql_fetch_array($doClassQry))
    {
        $subject = $x['subj_name'];
        $subjCode = $x['subjCode'];
        $section = $x['section'];
        $studentArr[] = $x['name'];
        $studentID[] = $x['studentID'];


    }
    echo "<thead>";
    echo "<tr><th colspan = 7>" . "This is your class: " . $subjCode . " " . $section . " : " . $subject . "</th></tr>";
    echo "</thead>";
    echo "<tbody>";
    echo "<tr>";        
    for($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($doClassQry); $i++)
    {
        if($i % 7 == 0)
        {               
            echo "</tr><tr><td id = '". $studentID[$i] . " '>" . $studentArr[$i] . "</td>";             
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<td id = '". $studentID[$i] . " '>" . $studentArr[$i] . "</td>";
        }

    }
    echo "</tr>";       
    echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";
```

?>

This is my php file (saveTest.php)

```
<?php
$absent = $_POST['absent'];
//echo "absnt" . $absent[] . "<br>";
echo count($absent);
?>
```

Comment: typo
It's supposed to be "<input type='hidden' name = 'absent[]' value = '" + currentCellText + "'/>"

Comment: Could you post your whole code? It's a bit vague right now.

Comment: use Firebug to check what is actually being passed to the page

Comment: use print_r. value showing is 0

Comment: tried to use method="get" to see what's being passed. it seems that there is no value being passed since only saveTest.php? is showing in the address bar. help please? :)

Comment: Are you trying to submit a javascript array into a php script? Please correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

Add name to hidden field:

```
 $("#collect").append("<input type='hidden' name="absent[] value= '" + currentCellText + "'/>" + currentCellText);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to submit a javascript array to a php script and then make use of it. You can make use of .each() function to loop through all the hidden values and adding them into the array. Then use $.post to submit the array to a php script.

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#btn_submit').click(function(){
        var array_hidden = [];
        $('input[type=hidden]').each(function(index){
            var current_value = $.trim($(this).val());
            array_hidden[index] = current_value;
        });

        $.post('arraysubmit.php', {'hidden_array' : array_hidden}, function(data){
            $('#results').html(data);
        });
    });
});
</script>
<?php for($x=0; $x<=10; $x++){ ?>
<input type="hidden" name="name[]" value="Name<?php echo $x; ?>">
<?php } ?>
<input type="button" id="btn_submit">
<div id="results"></div>
```

You can then access the array in the php script using the post variable and do whatever you want with it:

```
$_POST['hidden_array']
```